# Timezone conversion Layer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, timezone, momentjs

We are developing an application which is using angularjs, jade node etc. we are using the momentjs for date timezone and related stuff, just as a part of investigation i am trying to figure out the best place where we should induce this, Should we do it immediately in the UI layer when the angular model is updated OR can individual pieces of a date/time be passed down and the conversion be handled at the service layer.

Any suggestions on the same are highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Vaibhav

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "date timezone and related stuff".  Please show an example of how you would "do it" either way.  It's not clear at all what sort of conversion you are actually planning to do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you have two options -

1. user Filter
2. use Service

Using filter would be more of **declarative** and using service would look like more of **functional**.
Both ways you achieve modularization.

Filter would be my choice if the  requirement is to format the data we display to the user. If you want to re-use  you date related functions with in other controller, service - better go for creating a service.